# HQ2x Image Upscaling produces corrupt PNGs

Tags: ios, c, png

**Short question:**

Does anyone know why HQ2x is producing corrupt PNGs or knows of another implementation that supports transparency that I can try.

**Longer question:**

I'm attempting to use [HQ2x (with alpha support)](http://cdn.bitbucket.org/Mytskine/hqx/downloads/hqx-alpha_2011-02-20.zip) to produce upscaled images.

The problem however is that the following code produces corrupt PNGs.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testIcon.png"];
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];

uint32_t *imageData = (uint32_t *) malloc([data length]);
uint32_t *newImageData = (uint32_t *) malloc(image.size.width * 4 * image.size.height * 4 * sizeof(uint32_t));

[data getBytes:imageData];

hqxInit();
hq2x_32(imageData, newImageData, image.size.width, image.size.height);


FILE *file;
file = fopen("/Users/iPhone/Desktop/out.png","w");
fwrite(newImageData, image.size.width * 4 * image.size.height * 4 * sizeof(uint32_t), 1, file);
fclose(file);
```

Examining the first few bytes of the output, I can deduce that something has gone wrong as there are two intermingled [PNG Magic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) (`89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a`):

```
89 50 4E 47 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 0D 0A 1A 0A
```

The input image is not corrupted.

This is an objective-c program, but the important bits are in pure c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parts of this answer were discussed in chat. [(Transcript)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23222/conversation/hq2x-solution)

The blob you write to `/Users/iPhone/Desktop/out.png` is raw pixel data. You have to encode it as PNG because `hq2x_32` doesn't do it automatically.

If you're not decoding your PNG before you pass it to `hq2x_32` then your input and subsequently your output is wrong.

Take a look at [`hqx.c`](https://bitbucket.org/Mytskine/hqx/src/63f093060cc7/src/hqx.c), you can see that the data passed to `hq2x_32` is first decoded and then the output is manually encoded. Both transformations are handled using [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: What is hq2x_32 providing me with? Those âPNG tags are part of the output

Comment: I expect the input is wrong.. I shouldn't be providing PNG data, I should be providing RGB(A) data

Comment: @JamesWebster, I added a link to hqx's sources. Is it clear now?

Comment: Not really, I'm not really very familiar with image manipulation at this level. Mind if we [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23222/hq2x) about it?